# object reference not set to an instance of an object error in MVC search action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a simple project to display a contact list with the fields
Id, First Name, Last Name, Contact Number and email id using MVC and web API

I would like to display the details of a particular contact based on id. For that I have created a search action. I am getting an error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Please find the code below

```
Search.cshtml

@model ContactManagement.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

@section custom_scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".alert").css("display", "none");

            $("form").submit(function (event) {

                var contact = {
                    Id:$("#Id").val(),
                    FirstName:$("#FirstName").val(),
                    LastName:$("#LastName").val(),
                    ContactNumber:$("#ContactNumber").val(),
                    Email:$("#Email").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/contacts/"+contact.Id,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(contact),
                    success: function (resp) {
                        $(".alert").addClass("alert-success");
                        $(".alert").html("Item displayed successfully");
                        $(".alert").show("slow");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        $(".alert").addClass("alert-danger");
                        $(".alert").html("Failed to display the item");
                        $(".alert").show("slow");
                    }
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<h2>Search</h2>

<div class="alert">

</div>


<div>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I am getting error at the line @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |

Could someone help on this?

Comment: Check whether your Model is `null` ?

Comment: can you post the /api/contacts/ contact method code ?